# Gorm can't connect to local postgres db

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm new to GoLang and I`ve an issue with connecting my Go webserver with Postgres Database. 
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? 
All these credentials are correct btw. User exists, Password is correct, DB exists and belongs to the user.

```
package app

import (
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
)
func connectDB(){
    db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", "host=localhost port=5432 user=power_user dbname=local_db password=power_user")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("DB Connection failed")
    }   
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know whether the problem is with your DB connection/connectivity or with the `gorm` package. Is the machine this code runs on able to connect to the database with these credentials via another client like `psql`? What about a Go program that uses `database/sql` instead of `gorm`?

Comment: **Advice:** Switch up the code to print/log.fatal the err from the gorm.Open(). It should give the error. It is there for a reason. You can see what the error is and search up from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure about psql server is running, try to modify `pg_hba.conf`, locates at `/etc/postgresql/${version}/main/pg_hba.conf` usually:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD  
local   all             all                                     trust
```